# How many rows should show in datatable? does not appear on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatable but by default it shows top 10 rows, to see other rows you have to click on buttons at bottom to show other rows. I tried pagelength(), page.len(), "lengthChange": false etc but nothing work for me.

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var handleDataTableButtons = function() {
      if ($("#datatable-buttons").length) {
        $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
          dom: "Bfrtip",
          buttons: [
            {
              extend: "copy",
              className: "btn-sm"
            },
            {
              extend: "csv",
              className: "btn-sm"
            },
            {
              extend: "excel",
              className: "btn-sm"
            },
            {
              extend: "pdfHtml5",
              className: "btn-sm"
            },
            {
              extend: "print",
              className: "btn-sm"
            },
          ],
          responsive: true
        });
      }
    };

    TableManageButtons = function() {
      "use strict";
      return {
        init: function() {
          handleDataTableButtons();
        }
      };
    }();

    $('#datatable').dataTable();

    $('#datatable-keytable').DataTable({
      keys: true
    });

    $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();

    $('#datatable-scroller').DataTable({
      ajax: "js/datatables/json/scroller-demo.json",
      deferRender: true,
      scrollY: 380,
      scrollCollapse: true,
         
      scroller: true
        
    });

    $('#datatable-fixed-header').DataTable({
      fixedHeader: true
    });

    var $datatable = $('#datatable-checkbox');

    $datatable.dataTable({
        
      'order': [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
      'columnDefs': [
        { orderable: false, targets: [0] }
      ]
    });
    

      
$datatable.DataTable( {
    order: [[2, 'asc']],
    rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 2
    }
} ); 
      
      
      
    $datatable.on('draw.dt', function() {
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
      });
    });

    TableManageButtons.init();
  });
</script>
```

Other features of datatable working perfectly only SHOW 10,20,50,100 option does not appear on the top of the table. so user can select number of rows he want to see on same page.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging  and `scroller:true`  https://datatables.net/reference/option/scroller replaces the paging

Comment: Try with *just* `$(selector").DataTable()` first - you also have `.dataTable` at one point.  Do you have any console errors?   Can you provide a complete working snippet?